# querying WITH a $variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables, drop-down-menu

ive been trying all kinds of things and for some reason no matter what i do i cannot seem to query with a avriable... so far, here is my code, its not all of it, but ive pin pointed where my problem is....

```
<?php




    $hostname = 'localhost';        // Your MySQL hostname. Usualy named as 'localhost', so you're NOT necessary to change this even this script has already online on the internet.
 $dbname   = 'ServiceHistoryDB'; // Your database name.
 $username = 'root';             // Your database username.
 $password = '';                 // Your database password. If your database has no password, leave it empty.

// Let's connect to host
 mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host is failed, perhaps the service is down!');
 // Select the database
 mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('Database name is not available!');

$custnum = '1'; 

    function connect(){

        mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host is failed, perhaps the service is down!');
        mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('Database name is not available!');
    }

    function close(){
        mysql_close();
    }

        function query(){
            $mydata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE CustNum=1");
            while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
                echo '<option value="' . $record["Model"] . '">' . $record["Model"] . '</option>';
        }

    }










?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>testdropdown</title>
</head>

<body>

<select name="dropdown">
<?php query() ?>
</select>
<?php close() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what error or problem are you getting ? also what are you getting in `or die(mysql_error())` ?

Comment: Throw this away and start over with either mysqli or PDO :)

Comment: you can do this like `$mydata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE CustNum= $CustNum");` i assumed  CustNum is int

Comment: @Jack naahh.. you must solve problem first .. :P

Comment: @NullPointer So that it has to solved again later? No thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well, you can simply write in the variable like below:

```
$variable = 'someData';
"Select someColumn from yourTable where someColumn = $variable";
```

But, if you're doing this from a function you may need to declare a `global` variable to retrieve the value ***if*** the value was set outside the function:

```
function someFunc(){
    global $variable; // set above
    "Select someColumn from yourTable where someColumn = $variable";
}
```

## Using prepared statements

You should switch to `mysqli prepared statements` as they are more secure:

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($yourSQL)){
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $variable);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($thisHoldsThe_QueryResult);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: i think the global variable is what did it guys, thanks for your help in such a timely manner, next time i have questions ill definitely be posting them on here